# Skip arrayformula if the result of that formula is blank

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-forms, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have an array formula that looks like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(COUNTIF(B2:B, QUERY('Form Responses'!B2:G, "select G where B != ''"))=0, IFERROR(QUERY('Form Responses'!B2:G, "select B, G where B != ''"), "")))
```

It retrieves data from a different sheet that's connected to Google Forms.
With the first `IF` and `COUNTIF` I try to check whether the G column from the form response sheet is already present in the B column in my current sheet.
If that is not the case, I query column B and G.

However, if the value *is* present already, I don't want to query it, but I also don't want an empty line, which is now happening because of the `""` as the third argument for the `IF` statement.

Is there a way in which I can only query if not a duplicate, without adding an empty line otherwise?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the **`""`** is part of **`IFERROR`** not **`IF`** therefore try:

  ```
  =QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIF(B2:B, 
   IFERROR(QUERY('Form Responses'!B2:G, "select G   where B !=''", 0)))=0, 
   IFERROR(QUERY('Form Responses'!B2:G, "select B,G where B !=''", 0)), )), 
   "where Col1 is not null", 0)
  ```

Comment: Thank you for catching that! However, it still results in empty lines when the IF statement is false.

Comment: and you want what exactly? to remove empty lines in between and create a compact of results??

Comment: Yes. When the IF statement is false, it should go to the next entry in the query instead of returning an empty line.

Comment: @NielsKersic answer updated, try now

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks